# How do you turn on the c# language feature icons in the editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2019

I'm using  Visual Studio 2019 Professional and I can't find a way to turn on the icons shown below in the red boxes.

[image: see screen shot here]

I don't even know what they're called.

Thanks.

Comment: i'm using CodeRush extension, try it : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevExpress.CodeRushforRoslyn

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.